# Listener pattern vs Whiteboard pattern

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to understand the motivation of these two patterns.

I think the listener pattern is just a pub-sub, and the use case is mainly in a distributed manner, for example, the AWS SNS is just a distributed implementation of this pattern.

The whiteboard pattern is just a special case for listener pattern where it is allowed for listener to register specific event sources. This is also nothing special because this is what "subscribe" means in pub-sub, and in AWS SNS too.

To me, such xxx pattern is nothing but a new term. Are there other use cases for such patterns (either distributed or single instance) that I am missing?

Comment: It appears all of your questions are answered in [this article](https://www.osgi.org/wp-content/uploads/whiteboard1.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the listener pattern is just a pub-sub

They are similar but not the same.

- **Coupling**: In Publisher/Subscriber pattern, publisher is not aware of subscriber. Components are loosely coupled with a message broker as an event channel component in between. As opposed However, in Observer pattern Subject is aware of observers and maintains a record of the Observers.
- **Implementation**: Observer pattern is mostly implemented synchronously in a single application, while publisher/subscriber pattern is implemented asynchronously across the applications.

> the AWS SNS is just a distributed implementation of this pattern

Because of #2 above, SNS/SQS is rather a publisher/subscriber pattern.

> The whiteboard pattern is just a special case for listener pattern where it is allowed for listener to register specific event sources. This is also nothing special

The technical white paper [Listeners Considered Harmful: The “Whiteboard” Pattern](https://www.osgi.org/wp-content/uploads/whiteboard1.pdf) that Robert recommended in the comment is helpful with a simple Java example, where you can see the code amount in whiteboard pattern is dramatically reduced compared with listener pattern.